# jqGrid Not working sort process not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using local data.
Json value is in lsm object.

try to sort in rank and storeId. Both field not working.
Not able to find why its not working.

I am following as per given in the jqgrid site. Need to sort both column ascending and descending.

Need help to resolved the issue.

```
 $("#jqGrid-listofStoresMarked").jqGrid({
                 datatype: "local",
                 data: lsm,
                 height: 250,
                 colModel: [
                        {
                            label: 'Rank #',
                            name: 'rank',
                            width: 3,
                            align: 'left',
                            sorttype:'integer'
                        },  
                        {
                            label: 'Rank Update',
                            name: 'rank',
                            width: 5,
                            formatter: updateRank, 
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                     {
                            label: 'Store Id',
                            name: 'storeId',
                            width: 3,
                            index: 'storeId',

                            sorttype: function (cell, rowData) {
                                return (parseInt(rowData.storeId));
                            }
                     },
                     {
                            label: 'SKU & Pricing',
                            name: 'SKU_pricing',
                            width: 4,
                            formatter: checkValueSKU_pricing, 
                            align: 'left'
                     },
                     {
                            label: 'Future Pricing',
                            name: 'Future_pricing',
                            width: 4,
                        //  sorttype:'integer',
                            formatter: checkValueFuture_pricing, 
                            align: 'left'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Promotions',
                        name: 'Promotions',
                        width: 4,
                        formatter: checkValuePromotions, 
                        align: 'left'
                    },
                     {
                        label: 'Offers',
                         name: 'Offers',
                         width: 3,
                         formatter: checkValueOffers, 
                         align: 'left'
                     },
                    {
                            label: 'Full Update Mark Delete',
                            name: 'storeId',
                            width: 6,
                            formatter: formatLinkMarkDelete,
                            align: 'left'
                    }
                 ],

                 viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
                 height: 300,
                 rowNum: 8,
                 loadonce: true,
                 sortname: 'storeId',
                 sortorder: "desc",
                 pager: "#jqGridPager-listofStoresMarked"
             });
```

Comment: You've already asked this question, but you've provided no additional details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635756/jqgrid-sorting-not-working-properly

Comment: I already delete that post.

Comment: Could you provide some **test data** (`lsm`) with at least two items, which can be used to reproduce the problem? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Moreover you use in the code some custom formatters (almost in all columns). Could you include the code of the formatters too? It's allows to reproduce the problem, which you describe.

Comment: I am trying to sort column, when we used to click on the Table header.  Table data is my system local data.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you ! I can't purchase any product.    I have to fix this issue. I am trying to sort column on table which is loaded with Local system Data/json, when we used to click on the Table header.   I tried with localReader also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should fix clear bugs in your code. The object

```js
{
    height: 250,
    height: 300
}
```

In the same way you should never specify *the same* option twice.

Another important bug in your code: you specified multiple columns with the same `name` property more as once (look at two columns with `name: 'rank'` and two columns having `name: 'storeId'`).

The next problem. If you defined custom formatter (`checkValueSKU_pricing`, `checkValueFuture_pricing`, `checkValuePromotions`, `checkValueOffers`, `formatLinkMarkDelete`) you should define unformatter too (see description of  `unformat` callback [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)).

Short additional remarks about the options which you use: the option `loadonce: true` have no sense (it will be ignored) in case of usage `datatype: "local"`. The properties `align: 'left'` of `colModel` are default and can be skipped. The properties `index` can be removed too (see `index: 'storeId'`). The `sorttype` defined as functions (see `name: 'storeId'`) do the same as `sorttype: "integer"`. The predefined `sorttype` properties should be preferred.

The final remark: if you report a problem you should post more full code (see many custom formatters, which you use) and some test data (at least two items from `lsm` array, which you use as the value of `data` parameter). You should **always** write which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I recommend you to use the current version of free jqGrid (currently the version 4.13.2).